# Different return type when I switch for-loop generator order

Tags: scala

I have issue with these lines from the book "Scala for the Impatient", which I confirmed myself:

```
for (c <- "Hello"; i <- 0 to 1) yield (c + i).toChar
 // Yields "HIeflmlmop"
for (i <- 0 to 1; c <- "Hello") yield (c + i).toChar
 // Yields Vector('H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'I', 'f', 'm', 'm', 'p')
```

The first yields a `String` and the second yields a `Vector`? Yet I would expect them to return the same value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general the firs collection in the for comprehension determines the return type of `yield`.

Because:

In scala a for comprehension is syntactic sugar for `Collection` `.map`, `.flatMap`and so on. So the collection you start with is the collection you end up with.

The equivalent with `map` and `flatMap` for your code would be:

```
"Hello".flatMap(c => (0 to 1).map(i => (c + i).toChar))
```

or

```
(0 to 1).flatMap(i => "Hello".map(c => (c + i).toChar))
```